# How to access print dialog of chrome browser to do DOM manipulation with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, printdialog

Hello folk I just want to know is there a way for a chrome extension
to access the print dialog created by the chrome browser using Ctrl + P command
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you may call the following function:

```js
window.print();
```

You can learn more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp).
This can be called in most browsers without `special` priveleges.

Comment: I want to access the print dialog elements inside that dialog @myjobistobehappy

Comment: @Janaravi, Are you talking about something like [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)?

Comment: nope I want to access the dialog box from the content script or any way of accessing that dialog box to change that type save as